# MongoDB: converting existing docs from ISO date to string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
        {
        "_id" : 1.0,
        "item" : "abc",
        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-21T08:15:39.736Z")
    }
    {
        "_id" : 2.0,
        "item" : "def",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-01-14T08:15:39.736Z")
    }
    {
        "_id" : 3.0,
        "item" : "absc",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-17T08:15:39.736Z")
    }
.........
.........
```

I have millions of data existed in the DB with the above format where i needs to be update all the existing data **"date"** field value from ISO date to normal string like **"2017-01-21" (YYYY-MM-DD)**. Could it possible by using query or function in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update all the collection. Make sure you have a backup.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        { "$addFields": { "date":  {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }} }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks @Krishna, Great. You saved my whole day. It seems this will push the formatted data to the new collection. It would be works for me. But just wondering is there anyway that we can update data in the same collection instead of pushing the formatted data to the new collection. That would be really awesome.

Comment: @BhanuMakineni $out should point to same collection. Please observer the query aggregate and $out are done on same collection. That will update the same collection.

Comment: Awesome @krishna, Thank you. This is the perfect solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$dateToString` operator:

```
db.test.aggregate([ {$project: { item: 1, date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date"}}}}])
```

This will yield:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "date" : "2014-01-21" }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "def", "date" : "2015-01-14" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "absc", "date" : "2017-06-17" }
```

More reading can be found here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/

Comment: Thanks @kevin, This will just fetch the data with the required format and i was actually looking to update the data in the existing collection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function (doc) {    
 var month = ("0" + (doc.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
 var day = ("0" + doc.date.getDate()).slice(-2)   
 var year = doc.date.getFullYear()
 db.iso.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{date: year + "-" + month + "-" + day}})
});
```

Comment: I had tested your code and overall its looks good to me. But one thing that i noticed the "0" was missing in the MM and DD format and the output looks like {
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "item" : "def",
    "date" : "2015-1-1"
} And expecting : {
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "item" : "def",
    "date" : "2015-01-01"
}

Comment: This is working, but consuming lot of time to get it update. I personally tested with 1000 documents and it was taking 100 sec per 1000 doc. If we have millions of docs then this solution might not be fit. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: If you need to update that's one way to go. Maybe will get a better performance if you create a new property based on the date. An update query might perform better.

Comment: True, i will agree with you. Anyway, Thank you @Graciano.